# How do I distribute an energy load over a battery and generator?

Tags: battery-charging, dc-motor, parallel, generator

In a motor efficiency test, I use a motor, a generator, and a battery (Not an over-unity or perpetual machine attempt). I connect the motor's shaft with the generator and use the battery to initially power the motor. I connect the generator to power the motor as well now.

The question is, will the generator power the motor and the battery will only supply the difference, or will the load be equally distributed along with the battery and generator due to being connected in parallel? Diodes and other things will be used to ensure the current flows in the correct path and at the correct voltage. Assume both motor and generator are DC.
Here is a minimal diagram in hope of explaining what I said.[image]

In case, the latter is the answer of the load is equally distributed, is there a way to get the former where the battery only supplies the difference?

Comment: I should mention that I am a beginner in this so slow and easy explanations would be highly appreciated.

Comment: How important is it that the motor receive a stable voltage? What is its mechanical load?

Comment: Why have a battery at all if you also have a generator? Is it for fail-safe operation, or something else?

Comment: I think you misunderstood. The motor will be powering the generator which in turn will power the motor. Of course, since the system can never be 100% efficient, we will need the battery.

Comment: That makes even less sense? What powers the motor? If you're going from electrical power to the motor, to mechanical power, to the generator back to electrical power, why have the intermediate step?

Comment: @Reinderien it makes perfect sense, if you want to measure the efficiency of a motor, you need a load to absorb the power. You could use a brake, but using a generator as load doesn't wear brake pads and doesn't turn all the power into heat...

Comment: What is the motor rated power and voltage?

Comment: It sounds like you are building a dynamometer to measure motor power output. You can run the motor and the generator from the same power supply. What is missing from your diagram is the electronic speed controller between the motor and the battery. The generator also needs a controller of some sort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like a DC Dynamometer setup. This will not be a set it and forget it without some sophisticated controls. The ratio will change with the battery terminal voltage, temperature and the generator RPM. You need to consider the interrelationship between the temperature, battery voltage and the generator output voltage as they will change. You will need some controls to constantly adjust this to the optimum operating point. Its efficiency will always be less than 100% efficient therefore the battery will discharge.

The generator will have to put out more voltage then the terminal voltage of the battery realizing the battery and motor load will drag it down to the battery terminal voltage. If it is less the battery will supply the bulk of the energy. In the end the generator will be a current source into the battery. As the test stand runs the battery will start to discharge and its terminal voltage will drop the generator or battery has to increase its output supplying more current, if it cannot more of the load goes to the battery. The end result will be the battery will have to supply enough energy to make up for all losses in the system including heat.

Nice idea, using the generator this way is much better then dumping it into resistor banks. You can set this up and experiment with it to get a feeling what the optimum configuration will be. If your generator has a controllable field this will become easier as you just adjust the field excitation to control it. You could also add an external power supply or battery in a long term or life test.

Answer (score 0):

The answer will depend on the type of generator and your ability to regulate its output voltage.

Assuming that you're using a brushed DC motor and generator, you will have to account for the losses.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnJXng.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Let's say the motor and generator are identical and the motor rotates at 3000 RPM on 12 V, no load. When used as a generator it will give out somewhat less  - let's say 11.5 V at 3000 RPM. You should be able to see a problem here: the generator will never be able to exceed the motor terminal voltage and D2 will always be reverse biased.

I think that to get this to work you would have to increase the speed of the generator relative to the motor using gears or pulleys (or a generator rated for higher output).

If you had a generator with adjustable field windings then the situation is a little different but might surprise you.

- If the generator output voltage is less than the motor terminal voltage then the generator is unloaded and presents little resistance to the motor. (It only has to overcome bearing resistance and windage - air resistance.) The current drawn from the battery will be low.
- If you adjust the generator field current to increase the output voltage to the point where you exceed the motor terminal voltage by enough to forward bias D2 then current will flow, the load on the motor will increase and it will require more current. As you surmise, this can be fed back to the motor to reduce the battery current draw. The current will be regulated somewhat by the internal resistance of the generator (which will cause the output voltage to droop as more current is drawn). Adjusting the field current further will allow you to control this.

With a permanent magnet generator your options are much more limited.

I took a lab class demonstrating a similar technique for synchronous AC motors in college many decades ago and I found it fascinating. The clever thing is that it allows you to run a motor fully loaded but without the high energy cost of running against a dummy load or brake where all the energy would be dissipated as heat.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But the question remains that in the case that the current flows since the voltage exceeds the terminal voltage of the motor, how will the power draw be distributed?
Will it be equally distributed among the battery or generator or will the battery only provide the difference in energy while the motor is powered mostly by the generator?

Comment: See if https://electricalworkbook.com/characteristics-of-separately-excited-dc-generator/ helps.

Comment: If both devices are identical in kV/RPM and friction [Nms/rad] then the balance of diode current depends on the efficiency and acceleration. If unity efficiency, battery current is zero. The generator will always be slightly higher voltage with no load then when loaded and if the generator matches the battery voltage then current is shared.  With 2 diodes then current balances but is not loaded at max torque.

Answer (score 0):

No, this will not work as-is. Not for motor testing in general. It will have one or two stable operating points, but they will not be at the speed and motor load you want unless you're lucky.

Efficiency testing has to be done in two dimensions: **load torque and speed**. Both require active control. You'll want to set up a grid of torques and speeds and measure efficiency for each.

If you'd be OK with testing at a fixed motor speed, then an induction motor can be the load instead of a generator, recirculating the energy back to mains. But that's generally too restrictive.

So, there'll be two active circuits:

1. Motor speed controller, using an external speed sensor or motor EMF for feedback.

   Any typical PWM motor controller would do here.
2. Generator current controller.

   If the generator has a separate field winding, then this will be done by controlling the current through the field winding. The generator would need to be sized to produce the DC bus nominal voltage under maximum motor load current.

   If the generator is basically a motor running "backwards", this would be a boost converter with voltage set to the maximum battery charge voltage, and current limit set to whatever we want the torque to be.

The battery is not usually necessary. You can use a basic transformer+rectifier+capacitor smoothed power supply, and recirculate extra energy back to mains if the capacitor won't be able to store it. This would be the case only with rather high inertia in the system, where the inertial energy stored would be larger than the maximum energy that can be stored in the capacitors by bringing them above the rectifier output voltage.

One way of doing it is a grid-tie inverter enabled when the DC bus voltage goes above a threshold. This works well at high power levels.

At lower power levels, it can be simpler. A MOSFET switch can enable pulsed current flow from the capacitor to the secondary winding of a mains-fed transformer. The switch would be turned when two criteria are met:

1. Auxiliary rectifier voltage higher than about 80% of the peak voltage. This would be a resistor-loaded rectifier on the transformer secondary, with only a small smoothing capacitor, with RC time constant of a couple ms.
2. Capacitor voltage higher than 120% of the peak rectifier voltage.

I've done such recirculators for bipolar power supplies/active loads. They of course require supervisory circuitry to detect loss of mains - detecting too high conduction time on the recirculation MOSFET, and detecting loss of line voltage when the MOSFET is off, and detecting loss of current when the recirculation MOSFET is on (this is equivalent to line impedance going high).

There usually also needs to be a circuit to manage the recirculation symmetry so that the DC current across the transformer is zero.